# Time between Google Data Studio

Tags: time, looker-studio

I have two Fields:

| ACCEPTED_DRIVER_HOUR | DELIVERY_HOUR |
| --- | --- |
| 18:42:01 | 18:49:00 |

In Google Data Studio, these two fields are shown as **Text** Fields, so what I want to do is:

```
SUM(ACCEPTED_DRIVER_HOUR) - SUM (DELIVERY_HOUR)
```

This way, I can get how much time the driver took to deliver and order.

The problem is that Google Data Studio says that I can't do that because the field is **Text** and if I change to **Number**, it says **NULL** because the numbers have `:` between them; if I try to change to **Date Hour** it's not possible.

I already tried to create new fields using `CAST` and it shows the same error (**NULL**)

Comment: I think you can convert both into Time ISO Format and take the difference.
Date.prototype.toISOString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 0) Summary

Use **EITHER** #1 or #2; If #1 (DATETIME_DIFF) doesn't seem to work, try #2 (CAST & RegEx)

## 1) DATETIME_DIFF

One way that it can be achieved is by creating Date Time fields and then using the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) function to find the difference in `SECOND` after which the type can be set to `Duration (sec.)`; it can be achieved in a single Calculated Field as shown below where the Date used is 01 Jan 1970 (feel free to change the date as required, though ensure that both line 2 and line 3 below use the same date):

### 1.1) Calculated Field (Formula)

```
DATETIME_DIFF(
PARSE_DATETIME("%F%T", CONCAT("1970-01-01 ", DELIVERY_HOUR)), 
PARSE_DATETIME("%F%T", CONCAT("1970-01-01 ", ACCEPTED_DRIVER_HOUR)), 
SECOND)
```

### 1.2) Calculated Field (Type)

```
Numeric > Duration (sec.)
```

### 1.3) Calculated Field (Aggregation)

- It's set to [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) by default, though it can be changed as required, e.g. [`AVG`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518).

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3619edc1-762e-4cc9-914d-d6f6de79b255) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

## 2) CAST & RegEx

### 2.1) Calculated Field (Formula)

```
(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(DELIVERY_HOUR, "^([^:]+):") AS NUMBER)*60*60 +
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(DELIVERY_HOUR, ":([^:]+):") AS NUMBER)*60 +
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(DELIVERY_HOUR, ":(\\d+)$") AS NUMBER)) -
(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ACCEPTED_DRIVER_HOUR, "^([^:]+):") AS NUMBER)*60*60 +
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ACCEPTED_DRIVER_HOUR, ":([^:]+):") AS NUMBER)*60 +
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ACCEPTED_DRIVER_HOUR, ":(\\d+)$") AS NUMBER))
```

### 2.2) Calculated Field (Type)

```
Numeric > Duration (sec.)
```

### 2.3) Calculated Field (Aggregation)

- It's set to [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) by default, though it can be changed as required, e.g. [`AVG`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518).

[Added a New Page to the Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3619edc1-762e-4cc9-914d-d6f6de79b255/page/SNX4B) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]